# Is it possible to nest sqlite tables within each other?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Is it at all possible to nest tables within each other in sqlite using PDO?

Am i able to create table `"thisExtra"` inside table `"example"` inside row `"this"` at collumn `"y"`?

If it is possible, how would i go about doing so?
Would there be any hard-hitting performance implications?

The reason i ask this is because im used to accessing data from xml files - where i can put whatever i want wherever i want (within reason of course)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might wanna look into MongoDB / CouchDB or any other NoSQL DB.

Comment: I'll check them out for future ref. The current situation i am in is that i need to build a super lightweight "cms" so that editors can easily make/edit simple posts. Eventually i will move over to MySQL but for now there's not a huge amount of activity so sqlite should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A table is not a valid datatype for a field in SQLite. You will need to create a relation to another table.

As a side note, complex XML documents do not lend themselves to being stored in a relational database piece-wise. You should consider trying something different.

Comment: This directly answers my question, thankyou. And just to clarify - i don't intend to be using XML anywhere near the database(s) I want to rebuild my current project using nothing but sqlite. Thankyou very much for the response :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes, sort of.  You could store your subtables as blob objects.  However, that said this is a terrible, terrible idea.  It is completely counter to the purpose of using a relational database.  And accessing the data would be processing intensive and less than optimal. Did I mention this is a bad idea?

Comment: So it's a bad idea? heh, i figured it might be. Thanks for the response :)